# 5 people into 8 seat train compartment

Tags: permutations, combinations

question for you all.

In how many ways 5 people can be seated into an 8 seat train compartment, knowing that 2 people always sit by the window?

would it be  6 choose 3 + 5 choose 2 ? that would give me 30 ways.

Comment: It would actually be times instead of plus.  Also, since you're dealing with seating arrangements, these should probably be permutations instead of combinations.

Comment: How does seating look in a train compartment in the first place?  Are they all in the same row with only two seats by the windows and all facing the same way?

Comment: Two specific people, or any two sit by a window? Are there 4 window seats? You need to be way more specific.

Comment: Well sorry guys but this is exactly what it says on my test. I assume there are 2 window seats and no, it just says "exactly 2 people" so it doesn't matter who sits by the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Break it up via multiplication principle:

- Choose which seats are occupied
- Choose who sits in each occupied seat

Multiply the results to get the final total.

**Solution:**

(You say "*but this is exactly what it says on my test*", If this is a take-home exam or otherwise a test in progress, I will implore you not to look at the full solution but instead only at the hint above.  If this is studying an old test or trying to find the answer to a problem on a test you just took but has already been handed in, then go for it)

Assuming seating looks like $\square \underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\square$ with the squares being the windowseats:

.

> - Choose which seats are occupied: We already know the window seats will be occupied, so which of the center seats will be? there are 6 of them available, and only three will be used, so $\binom{6}{3}$

.

> - Choose who sits in each occupied seat: If it is two specific people who want a window seat (because lets face it... Steve just *has* to get what *he* wants... stupid Steve...), then first pick *which* window seat they each sit at, $2$ choices for the first, $1$ remaining choice for the second.  For the rest of the people, pick which order they sit from left to right, for $3!$ arrangements.  Multiplying we get a total of $3!2!=12$ different arrangements.

.

> Else, if it is not two *specific* people, but just so long as the window seats are occupied by *somebody*, simply start filling the seats chosen to be occupied with the people.  There are $5!$ number of arrangements.

.
If the shape of the traincompartment is in fact $\begin{array}{} 
\square \underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\\\square\underline{~}\underline{~}\underline{~}\end{array}$, the math still works.

> If it is some different shape though, it would need to be rethought a bit.  There are then $\binom{6}{3}\cdot 2\cdot 3!$ number of arrangements if the two people sitting by windows is specific, or $\binom{6}{3}\cdot 5!$ if the two people sitting by windows is nonspecific.

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming there are two window seats, pick 2 of 5 people to sit there and then arrange them in one of two ways.
Second, pick which 3 of the remaining seats 6 seats are to be
occupied and then arrange the three people  sitting there. Multiply.

Without the restriction about windows, the result would be ${}_8P_5 = 6720,$
so it seems clear that a result as small as 30 is out of the question.

If we were interested only in which seats are filled, but not by whom,
it is just a matter of deciding which of the 6 non-window seats
are occupied by the three people not sitting by the window: 20 ways.